# add random missingness and random noise in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, I want to add some random missingness in the data and add random noise

```
              22RV1      23132-87   639-V
exp_TSPAN6    7.951917   3.524705   12.04370
exp_TNMD      8.079243   3.580134   12.20077
exp_DPM1      8.509788   6.853905   4.406769
exp_SCYL3     7.642608   7.613985   8.741316
exp_C1orf112  3.231196   7.695874   10.668163
```

**Desired Output**

```
              22RV1      23132-87   639-V
exp_TSPAN6    7.951917   2.524705   12.04370
exp_TNMD      7.079243   Nan        13.20077
exp_DPM1      8.509788   6.853905   4.406769
exp_SCYL3     Nan        6.613985   Nan
exp_C1orf112  3.231196   7.695874   9.668163
```

I tried this function but its too slow for dataset with 1000 columns and 500 rows. is there an efficient way to add both randomness and noise?

```
insertNA <- function(df,NAratio) {
  sel <- sample( nrow(df)*ncol(df), size = NAratio*nrow(df)*ncol(df) )
  for (i in c(1:length(sel))) {
    a <- as.integer((sel[i]-1)/ncol(df)+1)
    b <- sel[i] - (a-1)*ncol(df)
    df[a,b] <- NA
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What did you already try to achieve to get your desired result? Did you encounter any problems, errors? We are here to help you, and not doing your project for you.

Comment: It would be more practical if you could paste the result of `dput(your_df)` a the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you want to add noise and missingness randomly there should still be some rules defined.

To add noise I use `rnorm` function and I change 20% of the values to `NA` here. You can change the conditions based on your requirement.

```
n <- nrow(df)
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) x + rnorm(n) * 
               sample(c(1, NA),n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)))
df
#               X22RV1 X23132.87    X639.V
#exp_TSPAN6   7.172716  5.179046 10.417945
#exp_TNMD     7.568185  3.794910 11.130833
#exp_DPM1     7.701909  6.799382  3.003337
#exp_SCYL3    8.034432        NA  8.510112
#exp_C1orf112       NA        NA 10.981735
```